# Which event is fired when drop action doesn't happen in html?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I want to capture the event when my drop action fails, either because the user did not drop at the right location or may be he himself has cancelled it by hitting 'Esc' key.

Comment: What about `ondragend` event? *The source of the drag will receive a dragend event when the drag operation is complete, whether it was successful or not. This event is not fired when dragging a file into the browser from the OS. See Finishing a Drag for more information.* -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop

Comment: dragend is fired even if it is a successful drop. I don't want to capture the successful drop here, rather only the failed drag/drop event.

Comment: You can check whether the drop event occurred on the target, and if not than it was dropped elsewhere. That would be the 'unsuccessful' drop.

Comment: Sounds technically correct.. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, I faced another issue while implementing this. In my case how my target would know that drop event dint fire? Drop event is the last event in the drag and drop series. After dragend gets fired, how my target would know that a future event i.e. drop event is going to get fired or not? Where do i put the check/validation?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51961/discussion-between-sidrocks-and-w-d)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this script. Took me some time to write and finish it. => <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zezicixu/3/edit)**</kbd>

If this is what you want, let me know.

**Note: =>** this code isn't compatible with legacy (browsers that don't have `HTML5` support) browsers (e.g. `IE8` etc)

1. First, we define our draggable element by setting its `draggable` attribute to `true`

   `<div id="draggable" draggable="true"> Drag this div </div>`
2. Then we define our `dropzone (target:where the element should be dropped on)`

   `<div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">Dropzone</div>`
3. We need to get the coordinates of the mouse when the element is being released, so we know if the mouse was released on the `dropzone` or not (I've put an `alert` notification showing whether the `dragend` event occurred on the `dropzone`. If on the `dropzone` than it will alert *`dropped on the dropzone`*, else it will alert  *`dropped not on the dropzone`*)

   `function cords(event)`
4. We also need to get the coordinates of the `dropzone` element, so we will be able to find where the `drop` event (successful or not (*manually cancelled (`Esc`) or dropped on the wrong place)) occurred.

   `var elTop = dragZone.getBoundingClientRect().top + getDocTopLeftPos().fT;`

   `var elLeft = dragZone.getBoundingClientRect().left;`

   `var elBottom = elTop + parseInt(getElProps(dragZone,'height'));`

   `var elRight = elLeft + parseInt(getElProps(dragZone,'width'));`
5. We will know whether the `drag` operation was successful or not via `(on)dragend` event

**HTML**

```
  <div id="draggable" draggable="true">
   Drag this div
  </div>

  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">Dropzone</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  #draggable {

    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom:50px;

  }

  .dropzone {

    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: brown;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align:center

  }
```

**Javascript**

```
//checking if the browser is Internet Explorer    
var isIEX = navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/);

var doc = isIEX ? document.documentElement : document.body;

function getDocTopLeftPos() {

    scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop;
    scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || doc.scrollLeft;

    clientTop = doc.clientTop || 0;
    clientLeft = doc.clientLeft || 0;

    fromTop  = Math.round(scrollTop - clientTop);
    fromLeft = Math.round(scrollLeft - clientLeft);

    return {fT:fromTop, fL:fromLeft}    

    }

//get the value of the property of the specified element
function getElProps(el,attr){

whaT_ = isIEX ? el.currentStyle : window.getComputedStyle(el);

getWhaT_ =  isIEX ? whaT_.getAttribute(attr) : whaT_.getPropertyValue(attr);

    return getWhaT_;

}

//getting the coordinates of the mouse 
function cords(ev) {

    if (ev.pageX == null && ev.clientX != null ) { 

    var html = document.documentElement;
    var body = document.body;
    ev.pageX = ev.clientX + (html && html.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) - (html.clientLeft || 0)
    ev.pageY = ev.clientY + (html && html.scrollTop || body && body.scrollTop || 0) - (html.clientTop || 0)

    }

    return {x:ev.pageX,y:ev.pageY}

}

var x,y;

var dragZone = document.getElementById("dropzone");

//getting our element's coordinates
//the mouse should be between these coordinates, otherwise that wouldn't be the dropzone

//from top
var elTop = dragZone.getBoundingClientRect().top + getDocTopLeftPos().fT;
//from left
var elLeft = dragZone.getBoundingClientRect().left;
//the height of the draggable element + its top coordinate
var elBottom = elTop + parseInt(getElProps(dragZone,'height'));
//the width of the draggable element + its left coordinate
var elRight = elLeft + parseInt(getElProps(dragZone,'width'));

    var dragElement;

    document.getElementById("draggable").addEventListener("dragstart",function(event){

        evt = event || window.event;

        if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox/)) event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)

    },false);

    document.addEventListener("dragstart",function(event){

        evt = event || window.event;

        //the element that is being dragged
        dragElement = evt.target || evt.srcElement

        //make our target half transparent;
        dragElement.style.opacity = 0.5;

    },false);

    document.addEventListener("dragend",function(event){

        console.log(x + ' ' + y + ' ' + elTop + ' ' + elLeft + ' ' + elBottom + ' ' + elRight);

        //if the dragged element was dropped at the right place
        if(x>elLeft && x<elRight && y>elTop && y<elBottom){

            alert('dropped on the dropzone');

            }else{

            //if the destination was wrong or the drag was cancelled (Esc)

            alert('dropped not on the dropzone')

            } 

            //reset our element's  transparency
            dragElement.style.opacity = 1;
            dragZone.style.background = "brown";

    },false);


    document.addEventListener("dragover",function(event){

        evt = event || window.event;

        x = cords(evt).x;
        y = cords(evt).y;

        console.log(x + ' ' + y);

        //this will prevent browser's default behaviour which will allow the drop event to occur

        if(evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault() ; else return false;

    },false);

    document.addEventListener("dragenter",function(event){

        evt = event || window.event;

        dropTarget = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

        //this will highlight potential drop target when the draggable element enters it

        if(dropTarget.className == "dropzone" ){

          dropTarget.style.background = "purple";

          }

    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("drop",function(event){

        evt = event || window.event;

        if(evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault() ; else return false;

    }, false);
```